# Pandas Datetime error: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'unicode'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, for-loop

I have a dataframe, D1:

```html
Date Symbol ICO_to
6/12/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
6/13/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
6/14/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
6/15/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
6/16/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
6/17/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
6/18/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
6/19/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
6/20/2017 18:00 MYST 5/30/2017
```

Below, I input logic to see if the Date column is less than (ICO_to - 5 days). If it is less, I want to drop all rows in this specific dataframe:

```
D1.Date = pd.to_datetime(D1.Date) 
D1['Date'] = D1['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

D1.rename(columns={'ICO to': 'ICO_to'}, inplace=True)
D1.ICO_to = pd.to_datetime(D1.ICO_to)

for index, row in D1.iterrows():
    if D1.loc[index, 'Date'] < (D1.loc[index, 'ICO_to']-pd.Timedelta(5, unit='d')):
        D1.drop
```

But I get the error, referring to the if statement in the above loop:

```
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'unicode'
```

I think it's because you can't subtract the Timedelta value from the Datetime value, but am not sure. How can I make this for loop logic work?

Comment: What problem are you _actually_ trying to solve? You don't need a loop, you can likely 100% vectorize this. I'd like to see your expected output, I can help you that way :)

Comment: @COLDSPEED I have a number of different cryptocurrency tickers all in same type of dataframes, that I merge later into one dataframe. If the Date value is <5 days before the ICO_to value, then I want to drop all rows associated to this particular dataframe. That way they won't show up on the merged file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorise your calculation. Here is one way:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['ICO_to'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ICO_to'])

df = df.loc[~(df['Date'] < (df['ICO_to']-pd.Timedelta(5, unit='d'))), :]
```

**Explanation**

- The condition `~(df['Date'] < (df['ICO_to']-pd.Timedelta(5, unit='d')))` produces a Boolean array. `~` signifies negative. All `True` components of the array signify rows that are kept; likewise `False` are removed.
- The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) is an ideal place to learn about *vectorising* your calculations.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit of a newb at python so I usually use for loops. But this vector works great.